# Create Dummy in Panel Data based on multiple Conditions in R

Tags: r, dataframe, matching, dummy-variable, panel-data

I am Jonas and completely new to R or coding in general. I have the following problem.
I have a paneldataset, which Looks conceptually like this (I made Approximation in Excel since the dataset I am actually using in R is way to large)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBNh1.png)

And a second dataframe which looks like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9VDa.png)

What I want to create is a dummyvariable which equals and Zero otherwise in the first dataframe depending on the follwing conditions:
1) The ID in both dataframes must be the same
2) The year in the second dataframe must be smaller than the year in the first dataframe, but at the year in the second dataframe must also be bigger than the year of the same ID with the prevois year in the paneldata.

More Explanation:
The first dataframe I have includes observations with ID as the Identifier and year as time of the Observation. The second dataframe indicates if something happend to the ID and when. I Need a dummy which indicates 1 if something happened between the years of the Observation and the prevoius observation in the first dataframe.

In the end it should look like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EtVs.png)

Sorry for the poor explanation but I am completely new to this. Any help is very much appreciated.

Cheers, 
Jonas

Comment: please share the dataframes in R code (example for your first dataframe below). this way people can use your code. also, the practice here is to remove anything that's not the question itself (like "hi I'm Jonas", yes it's a cold place, but you'll get used to it :))
 
`dfx = data.frame(ID=c(1,"v",1,2,3,3,4,4,4,5),Year=c(2000,2005,2010,2003,2008,2012,2001,2003,2008,2006))`

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).